Google apps script Selecting sheets from dynamic menu in google sheets
I have a spreadsheet with very big amount of sheets and it's now hard to find the right sheet in sheet list at the bottom.
I'd like to use script that generates menu with list of sheets (1 menu item = 1 sheet) in this spreadsheet. And so that clicking on this menu item changes active sheet to the selected sheet
I tried to google it, but I've only found ways to manually create link to each sheet and I don't understand how to make a dynamic number of menu items with links on every sheet. I would be glad of your help.

Could you please elaborate further on your expected output? Right now I don't really see the difference between what you're asking and the built-in list menu "at the bottom", as you mention.

In Google Sheets on the web, there is a "hamburger" button ㆔ between ➕ and tab names in the left end of the tab bar. Click it to do what you ask. Alternatively, press Control+J to open the name box, type the first few letters of the sheet name, press Arrow down, and press Enter.

I'm dumb and I forgot about the hamburger button. Thank you all for your replies. And also big thanks for ctrl+J shorcut, it seems good

Dynamically changed active sheet
To achieve the ability to dynamically set the active sheet in a spreadsheet file by, you can implement a an apps script program that contains a drop down menu that contains all the sheet names in the spreadsheet and upon selecting an item in the dropdown, the corresponding sheet will be activated.
The script below uses apps scripts onOpen and OnEdit simple triggers. Upon opening the Spreadsheet, the script will create a dropdown menu on sheet named “Menu” you can then select an option(a sheet name) and that sheet name will be activated.
Script
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheetNames = sheets.map(sheet => sheet.getName());

  var cell = ss.getSheetByName("Menu").getRange("A1");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(sheetNames).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = ss.getRange("A1");
  var selectedSheetName = cell.getValue();

  var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => sheet.getName());
  if (sheetNames.includes(selectedSheetName)) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(selectedSheetName));
  } else {
    Logger.log("Invalid sheet name selected: " + selectedSheetName);
  }
}

Output

References: apps script data validation, apps script triggers

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
